# Why Application.Selection.Range.Start returns incorrect value sometimes?

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

Situation context - MS Word addin.
Langiage - C#
 Problem:

I'm trying to get current cursor position. I'm using `Application.Selection.Range` as it returns `InsertionPoint`. After each `Space,Tab` or `Enter` keys pressing I do the following: `MessageBox.Show(Application.Selection.Range.Start.ToString());` **Sometimes** I see MessageBox with the correct value **sometimes** `actual_value_of_insertion_point_position+128`. Why insertion point index sometimes increased to 128? I'm doing nothing specific I'm just typing some text, press Space and see sometimes correct value as expected someimes not.

**UPDATE**
Actually, my problem is deeper - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888104/how-programatically-set-text-styling-in-ms-word) my other SO question with detailed description. My plan:

1) When user types `Space` remember insertion point - it returns **next** future letter's position.
2)If user typed some letter and previous key was Space, it means user typing first letter of some new word. Create range as the following `Application.ActiveDocument.Range(remembered_pos,rem_pos+1)` and style it as you want.

My code

```
 private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int pointerCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                string pressedKey = ((Keys)pointerCode).ToString();

                IntPtr curHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

                if(curHandle==wordHandle)
                {

                    //MessageBox.Show(app.ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID +" "+ WdLanguageID.wdKazakh);
                    if(pressedKey.Equals("Space")||pressedKey.Equals("Return")||pressedKey.Equals("Tab"))
                    {

                        Word.Range r = app.Application.Selection.Range; 
                        MessageBox.Show(app.Application.Selection.Type.ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show("-"+r.Start.ToString()+"-"+r.End.ToString()); // sometimes +128!


                    }
                    else if(firstAfterSpace!=-1)
                    { // right now doesn't make sense 
                        MessageBox.Show(firstAfterSpace.ToString());
                        //Word.Range rng = app.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(firstAfterSpace,firstAfterSpace+1);
                        //MessageBox.Show("-"+rng.Text+"-");
                        //rng.Underline = Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
                        firstAfterSpace = -1;
                    }



                }

            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

Comment: Is your question purely informational? Do you only wish to know why this is the way it works or do you try to accomplish something and this gets in your way? In the later case - it would be helpful if you could describe what it is you wish to accomplish.

Comment: you could also point out exact situation when you have `value + 128` but not only mention `sometimes`. This could be helpful if one want to check this behaviour on his/her own machine.

Comment: @Vadim,I want to get current cursor position. I mean integer index. I used `Application.Selection.Range.Start` as it returns insertion point's index - exactly what I need. It works but sometimes returns incorrect value. I want to know how I can solve this problem. May be there exist other way to get cursor position.

Comment: @KazJaw, test case description: I typed some text, pressed `Space`. Expected value of cursor position is `text.length+1`. MessageBox shows `text.length+1+128`. When I press Space more and more sometimes I see expected value.

Comment: my comment intention was to get more information of your document structure as there is nothing unusual when pressing Space,Tab and Enter and their strange result in `.Start` property result. Are there any tables? Fields? ContentControls? etc. What if you check `.End property`- does it behave strange as well? could you upload your document for some tests?

Comment: @Baurzhan - 1. I just tested it on my machine and everything seems to work fine, anything else you can tell us? 2. I understand your question, I just wanted to know if that's you final goal. Perhaps you don't *need* to get the cursor position the way you're trying to do to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @KazJaw, i just created new document and started typing) nothing special.

Comment: @Vadim, yes you are right my problem is deeper. Here my other SO question which describes my actual problem. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try different way of setting range after someone pressed `Space, Return or Tab` assuming that **you search for the word before any of these'characters'**.

Here is the code which you could place into your `If statement`:

```
    Word.Range r = appWRD.Application.Selection.Range;
    Word.Range tmpR = r.Previous(Word.WdUnits.wdWord,2);
    MessageBox.Show("-" + tmpR.Start.ToString() + "-" + (r.Start-1).ToString());

    //set temporarily for checking word text
    tmpR = appWRD.ActiveDocument.Range(tmpR.Start, r.Start -1 );
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Word found: {0}!", tmpR.Text));
    //this shows it doesn't include any tab or space
```

**Tip.** There are a lot of `Range modification methods` in Word but some of them don't work correctly. `Previous` works fine in this situation according to my test.

Comment: Thanks for your investigations. Actually, i need to remember the range not before space but after. A saw you've answered on my other question - I know how change style of some range I don't know how to change style of first letter after space. I accepted your answer because `Previous` works fine. Unfortunately I still can;t acquire profit from it( Anyway thanks for response I accepted your answer as you really helped me solve `128 shift` problem) Moreover, I tried to combine 2 answers - getting cursor pos with `Previous` and simply setting `rng.Font = ...` - doesn't work. I have to go deeper)

Comment: Glad was able to help. As far as I understood both questions are part of one project therefore I suggested using `.Previous`. I did some test and above code help to change last word without `space` which follows it. If so, next word was written in default style.

Comment: BTW, you could possibly find it out on your own but... `Previous method` second parameter is set to `2` at the moment. However, it could be required to change it to `1` for `spaces` and kept `2` for `Tabs and enters` according to my test.

Comment: @Baurzhan, I've also add the other suggestion to the other question of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're using global hook event. But I don't know the reason. I have just experimented it. When I use the global hook, the index of the range seems to be increased by 128.

Answer (score 0):

The same behaviour is observed when you access `Selection.Start` and `Selection.End` from `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

I think the reason is the optimization of text buffer manipulations in Word. Instead of inserting one char it inserts a block of 128 chars but postpones updating of `Selection.Start` value.

But luckily we can always obtain the correct value of `Selection.Start` from `selection.Previous(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1).End`.

So the code to get the correct Selection Start and End looks this way:

```cs
var selection = app.Selection.Range;

var selStart = selection.Previous(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1)?.End ?? 0;
var selEnd = selStart + selection.End - selection.Start;
```