# how to change font color in a word document style

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to change the font color of a word document style using office.interop but the color doesn't change. Any idea?
I tried it in two different ways.
The 1st is by trying to change the color of heading style in ms word:
here's some code:

```
Application appWord=new Application();
Document doc=new Document();
ListGallery gallery=appWord.ListGalleries[WdListGalleryType.wdNumberGallery];
ListTemplate template =gallery.ListTemplates[4];
Style style=doc.ListTemplate[2];
style.LinkToListTemplate(template,1);
style.Font.ColorIndex=WdColorIndex.WdBlack;//doesn't work
doc.saveAs2(path);
```

The 2nd way is by trying to set the color of the range or selection after inserting the file into ms doc:

```
Paragraph p3 = wordDocument.Paragraphs.Add();
Range r3 = p3.Range;
//r3.Font.TextColor = WdColor.wdColorBlack;

var filename=String.Format("{0}Resources/TEST1.html", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
String newString=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("</body>","<p>1</p></body>");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, newString);
appWord.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;
r3.InsertFile(filename);
//r3.Font.olorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBrightGreen;
```

**edit:**

here is the solution:

```
(document.Styles[WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2]).Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How programatically set text styling in ms word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888104/how-programatically-set-text-styling-in-ms-word)

Comment: @rajeeshmenoth not quite the same thing. i want to change the default color of a style and not just a selection. cause i insert an html file to a word range! and the html file contains heading styles!,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

here is the solution:

```
(document.Styles[WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2]).Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlack;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have written in your program

`style.Font.ColorIndex=WdColorIndex=WdBlack;`//doesn't work

Correct the above line as

```
style.Font.ColorIndex=WdColorIndex.WdBlack; // this will work
```